# grep only the exact match line

Tags: regex, awk, grep

I am trying to grep the exact match line.

```
grep '^listen' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf

listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock
listen.acl_users = apache,nginx
listen.allowed_clients = 127.0.0.1
```

I want it to show only the following

```
listen = /run/php-fpm/www.sock
```

not the other lines. how to do that?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `grep` to make sure there is at least one space or tab character or `=` after matching `listen` at start:

```sh
grep  '^listen[=[:blank:]]' file
```

or do string comparison of first field using `awk`:

```sh
awk -F '[=[:blank:]]+' '$1 == "listen"' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `grep -P` like so, with `\s` meaning whitespace:

```
grep -P '^listen\s' /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Here, `grep` uses the following option:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
[perlre - Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre)

Comment: Thank you, good solution, can you explain more on flag -P with escape sequence \s ?.